# Sterilizing javascript in <a onclick="sth" href =""> in user input

Tags: javascript, php, xss

From the user submitted post there are things like

```
<a onclick="sth()" href ="legitlink.html">some content</a>
```

I would like to preserve the link so that the link can still be display, but the javascript part should be sterilized

```
<a href="legitlink.html">some content</a>
```

How can this be done in php? Is there some extensions or frameworks that handle these kind of work automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to make this by yourself - I bet you forgot some malicious code parts. There are testet libraries, which do a great job.
I.e. have a look at [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```